# Universal Programming IDE

Tags: ide

I'm searching for a good IDE that supports multiply languages and compiling of them, syntax highlighting, uploading of microcontroller projects etc.

The problem is; I currently have 8 different IDE:s, each for a different language (Programmer's Notepad (PHP, HTML), Qt Creator (C++ with Qt libraries), Eclipse C++ (C++), Eclipse Java (Java), Processing (Processing), Arduino IDE (Arduino), AVR Studio (AVR (C)), Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express (Visual C++)), and I am sure more will be added to the list.

So what I'm searching for now is a Windows (or cross plattform) Programming IDE with support for as many languages as possible, and not only with syntax highlighting (PN), I want ONE button to compile a program and ONE button to Run/Upload the program, not multiply from a list.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: IMO, all you're going to get is a "jack of all trades, master of none."

Comment: I use [Geany](http://Geany.org).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Eclipse**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) with according plugins can support almost all of the above, except maybe for VC++

Comment: I didn't knew there are so many plugins for Eclipse! After seeing almost all the languages I need can be supported by eclipse that is definitatly the IDE I'm going to use, THANKS!